# How to return a column value only once in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need help with this. I have a database that displays product type titles.

My code so far is:

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT type FROM certs ORDER by type") or die("Could not execute query"); 


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
{

   $product .= "<h1>".$row["type"]."</h1>";
}

echo($product);
```

which returns

```
<h1>MR001</h1>
<h1>MR001</h1>
<h1>MR002</h1>
<h1>MR003</h1>
<h1>MR003</h1>
<h1>MR004</h1>
<h1>MR004</h1>
<h1>MR004</h1>
```

etc., but I need it to only return the same value once?

Like

```
<h1>MR001</h1>
<h1>MR002</h1>
<h1>MR003</h1>
<h1>MR004</h1>
```

STUCK.COM HELP!!!

Comment: `select distinct type from` ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **DISTINCT** in the SQL Query..
Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM certs ORDER by type") or die("Could not execute query");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) 
{     
   $product .= "<h1>".$row["type"]."</h1>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Change your query to use `DISTINCT`, which will only return unique rows:

```
mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM certs ORDER by type")
```

---

For ease of use, your entire corrected code will be as follows:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM certs ORDER by type") or die("Could not execute query");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
{
    $product .= "<h1>".$row["type"]."</h1>";
}
echo($product);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to do this with MySQL using `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM certs ORDER by type
```

Read more about [using DISTINCT in MySQL](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `SELECT DISTINCT type`. . . .

Answer (score 2):

Try `DISTINCT`:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT type FROM certs ORDER by type"
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at GROUP BY and also the DISTINCT operators.

For your specific example:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM certs ORDER by type") or die("Could not execute query");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use group by

```
SELECT type FROM certs GROUP BY type
```

( bit offtopic ) - it is better to have type definitions in separate table ( eg not in certs , but in own table ) - and linket thru foreign key ( eg. type_id instead of type - it will 1 for MR001, 2 for MR002 etc )

For listing of certs with type names use JOIN

Comment: group by goes before order clause and in this case is not necessary because group by already does the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `SELECT DISTINCT`. You may want to view the full [MySQL syntax for Select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).